# Как правильно спарсить данные JSON?

Tags: php

Есть вот такой JSON:

```
"data": [
    {
      "updated_at": 1576048969000,
      "prices": {
        "last": 5300,
      },
      "name": "Jacket",
    },
    {
      "updated_at": 1576048969000,
      "prices": {
        "last": 2000.12,
      },
      "name": "T-shirts",
    }
]
```

Как можно спарсить значения в price обратившись при этом к name?
Что-то типа как в SQL, SELECT price FROM data WHERE name = Jacket (чтоб была понятна логика)

Comment: перебор data в цикле

Comment: @Volodymyr а подробнее можно?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

При условии что не будет повторяющихся имен

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);

$full = array();

foreach ($arr["data"] as $value) {
  $full[$value["name"]] = $value;
}
```